# Generating random starting points for incoming objects in Flash ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

we have this game where you control an avatar in the middle of the stage that defends itself from incoming projectiles. If it hits them with its arms or legs you get a +1, but if they hit the head or torso you get a -1. But cant figure out how to spawn them randomly along a given path. See picture below. Want them to come in from the sides but have the same "destination-area" - which would be the head & torso.

Heres the image, couldnt post image, because I didnt have enough points apparently.

http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/517/flashobjects.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to initialize the X value of each spawned particle to be either less than 0 (coming from the left), or greater than the stageWidth (coming from the right). Then, you need to put them on a trajectory toward the head or torso.

logic for the starting point could be something like:

```
var x:int = (Math.random() > .5) ? -10 : stage.stageWidth + 10;
var y:int = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight);
```

The actual traveling of the particles towards the character can be done a bunch of different ways. But the simplest might be to just move each particle on the Event.ENTER_FRAME event a little bit closer to the their targets. Some simple trigonometry should get you there.

Alternatively, you could use some scripted Tweens to just move the particles to their destination over a desired period of time.

Comment: Good answer. It's also possible to use a vector implementation instead of trig, if you know the starting x/y coordinates and the ending x/y coordinates. Then, you can set velocity as a variable, and then use that variable as a scalar for your normalized vector.